# Ключевое слово this в параметрах метода

Tags: c#

В процессе изучения заметил конструкцию метода:

```
public void myMethod(this int[] array)
{
// ignore
}
```

Подскажите, какая роль ключевого слова this в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> какая роль ключевого слова this в данной ситуации?

То определение метода, что вы привели не имеет никакого смысла, и скорее всего выдаст ошибку компиляции. Наверно вы потеряли `static` и имели ввиду это

```
public static void MyMethod(this int[] array)
{
// ignore
}
```

Это уже похоже на определение метода расширения. Чтобы точно стать таковым, он должен располагаться в статическом классе.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void myMethod(this int[] array)
    {
    // ignore
    }
}
```

Теперь в пространстве имён, в котором объявлен MyExtensions и во всех модулях, в которые будет добавлен `using` этого пространства имён, у массивов `int` появится метод `MyMethod()`

```
var arr = new int[4]{0,1,2,3};
arr.MyMethod();
```

При выполнении метода в качестве первого аргумента выступит собственно сам массив. Если бы вы добавили еще параметров в MyMethod(), то они получали бы аргументы из оператора вызова `()`.

Нужно иметь ввиду, что методы расширения это приём нарушающий классические ООП принципы. Но в тоже время такая замечательная вещь как LINQ реализована на их основе.

Answer (score 3):

Это метод расширения (Extension Method)

> Методы расширения позволяют "добавлять" методы в существующие типы без
>   создания нового производного типа, перекомпиляции и иного изменения
>   первоначального типа. Методы расширения представляют собой особую
>   разновидность статического метода, но вызываются так же, как методы
>   экземпляра в расширенном типе. Для клиентского кода, написанного на
>   языках C#, F# и Visual Basic, нет видимого различия между вызовом
>   метода расширения и вызовом методов, фактически определенных в типе.

Это значит, что вы можете вызвать

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
int i = myClass.Foo();
```

вместо

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
int i = Foo(myClass);
```

Это позволяет сделать "текучий интерфейс" (fluent interface)

Вот [здесь](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/fluent-code-in-c/) показан пример

Comment: У автора в вопросе метод не статический. Опечатка, наверное.